# How can i convert a string to a Document (DOM) with charset in ISO-8859-1

Tags: java, string, dom, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I'm converting a string received in a web service to a Document (DOM) xml, like this:

```
Document file= null;
String xmlFile= "blablabla"; //latin1 encodeing

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
this.file = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlFile)));
```

But the string is encoded with ISO-8859-1 (latin1) and when I read a node of this Document, I have some errors. How can I create correctly DOM object with ISO-8859-1 encoding?or how can I read a node with the encoding Latin 1 in a string???

Comment: what is the encoding param of the xml?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

Comment: Java strings are always UTF-16; the real question becomes _"how do I read ISO-8859-1 data to a String?"_ State the data source you read the character data from.

Comment: exactly, is the data in the string itself correct?

Comment: I think so, but the information is sent from a console app (using c#) to a web service (using java) the protocol is like this nameOfTheMethod(String xmlFile, int type)

Comment: This code does not make sense. If the value of the String xmlFile is set to "blablabla" in your program, then it is not an latin1 string, but a java String. If it is read from a stream, then the problem is the way the stream is read into a String. You should understand that a String has NO ENCODING! It is a sequence of characters... On the other hand, a sequence of bytes uses an encoding to represent characters. On the same note, a DOM object uses String, hence it does not have an encoding...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
this.file = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlFile.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));
```

Comment: If I use this initialization when I read a string with the character ó I read an ?, like: GOL TELEVISIÓN --> GOL TELEVISI?N

Comment: It looks like the key of this thing is what @McDowell said. If a java string is always UTF-16, then use getBytes("UTF-16"). If the content is coming from a file, you can use the "ISO-8859-1" param. Try using UTF-16 and let's see what happens, otherwise the problem is forwarded to the data source.

Comment: I have check with UTF-16 and is not working...also I have reviwed data source and it's ok. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

**Foreword**

String have no encoding as they represent a sequence of characters (which are abstract entities defined in unicode standard).

Byte sequences have an encoding and may be interpreted as a sequence of Character (provided that you tell java how to interpret it).

**Your problem**

In your problem, your data is stored into a String. Hence it has already been interpreted as a  sequence of characters. Apparently the interpretation was incorrect.

Depending on your problem and the way you know the encoding of your data, there are 2 options:

**Solution 1 (may be the best):**

DO NOT INTERPRET the data you receive and keep it as a byte sequence (Stream or byte[] or ByteArray). Then pass this Byte sequence directly to your DOM parser (it will correctly decode the xml file, whatever its encoding, provided that the  markup is correct.

**Solution 2 (may be the only possible depending on the way you get the data):**

Reencode the String as a ByteArray as mentioned in @ThOrndike's answer:

```
this.file = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlFile.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));
```

This will only work if you are sure the String has been correctly interpreted in the first place.

Apparently, it is not the case here and it seems that the library that give you the String, already interpreted it as an UTF-8 byte sequence (replacing all erroneous bytes by '?', it is the behavior of the UTF-8 readers). In that case, you cannot do anything as the original byte has been lost.

Your only hope is solution 1, or find a way to force the library that gives you the String to interpret it correctly.